# Eating habits and attitudes

Tags: data-request, medical, food

I have a question, which is along the lines of a previously asked one, regarding people's eating habits, ideally a "food journal" type of thing that has data from individuals showing what they ate at what times/days.

However, I also need information with regards to their attitudes towards the food they consume, e.g:

- obsession about calories,
- avoidance of fat/sugar/processed food out of fear of its perceived un-healthinesss,
- rigidity,
- etc (think along the lines of eating disorders, particularly specific avoidance/restriction or orthorexia if someone is familiar with that)

Ideally this would be on the level of individuals as well as in conjunction with demographic data.

I want to try out something new for my Dissertation and thus lack knowledge with regards to where to get high quality open data from.

Comment: Especially if this is for your dissertation, it seems that you should make a plan to collect the data yourself. I doubt you'll find an existing open data set of this material. You could publish the data you collect and help the community.